# C Programming segfault on scanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have written the following code segment and am having trouble understanding why it would not get to the last printf line. I get a segfault immediately after line 4. The kill_char is just used to kill the 'enter' character added in the previous scanf. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
int remove = 0;
char kill_char = 'a';
printf("Enter the product number to be removed: ");
scanf("%d", &remove);
scanf("%c", &kill_char);
printf("Does not get here");
```

EDIT:
Full code is as follows, with the error in the removeProduct function

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct product_node {
char *supply_type;
long number;
char *description;
float price;
int quantity_bought;
float retail_price;
int quantity_sold;
struct product_node *next;
};

struct product_node *head;//declaring head out here 
//allows the list to be in scope for the functions

/*Function Prototypes*/
void addProduct();
void removeProduct();
void listProduct();
void listSupplierTypes();
void supplierTypeProfit();
void totalProfit();

void addProduct(){
    char kill_char = 'a';//used to kill the enter characters
    struct product_node *new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct product_node));

    printf("\nEnter a string for type: ");
    scanf( "%s", &(*new_node).supply_type);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the product number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &(*new_node).number);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the description: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*new_node).description);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the wholesale price: ");
    scanf("%f", &(*new_node).price);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the quantity bought: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*new_node).quantity_bought);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the retail price: ");
    scanf("%f", &(*new_node).retail_price);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Enter the quantity sold: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*new_node).quantity_sold);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);

    struct product_node *walker;
    walker = head;
    int can_insert = 1;
    while (!(walker == NULL))
    {
        if (((*walker).number == (*new_node).number) && ((*walker).supply_type == (*new_node).supply_type))
        {
            can_insert = 0;
        }
        walker = (*walker).next;
    }

    if (can_insert==1)
    {
        (*new_node).next = head;
        head = new_node;
        printf("Insertion Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nERROR INSERTING:This product name and number is already in the list\n");
    }
    free(new_node);
}
void removeProduct(){
    int remove = 0;
    char kill_char = 'a';
    printf("Enter the product number to be removed: ");
    scanf("%d", &remove);
    scanf("%c", &kill_char);
    printf("Does not get here");
    struct product_node *walker;
    struct product_node *prev;
    prev = head;
    walker = (*head).next;

    if ((*prev).number == remove)
    {
    head = walker;
    }//points head to second node to remove first

    while (!(walker = NULL))
    {
        if ((*walker).number == remove)
        {
            (*prev).next = (*walker).next;
        }
    }
}
void listProduct(){
    printf("Still unsure what defines a supplier...");
}
void listSupplierTypes(){
    printf("Same as above");
}
void supplierTypeProfit(){
    printf("Again");
}
void totalProfit(){
    float total = 0.0;
    struct product_node *walker;
    walker = head;
    while(!(walker == NULL))
    {
        total += ((float)(*walker).quantity_sold * (*walker).retail_price) - ((float)(*walker).quantity_bought * (*walker).price);
        walker = (*walker).next;
    }
    printf("Total Profit is: $%.2f\n", total);
}

int main()
{
    head = NULL;

    char *temp_type;
    char *temp_description;
    int temp_number, temp_quantity_bought, temp_quantity_sold;
    float temp_price, temp_retail_price;

    while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        scanf( "%s %ld %s %f %d %f %d\n", &temp_type, &temp_number, &temp_description, &temp_price, &temp_quantity_bought, &temp_retail_price, &temp_quantity_sold);

        struct product_node *new_node;
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct product_node));
        (*new_node).next = head;
        head = new_node;

        (*head).supply_type = temp_type;
        (*head).number = temp_number;
        (*head).description = temp_description;
        (*head).price = temp_price;
        (*head).quantity_bought = temp_quantity_bought;
        (*head).retail_price = temp_retail_price;
        (*head).quantity_sold = temp_quantity_sold;
    }

    freopen("/dev/tty", "rw", stdin);

    int done=0;
    int selection=0;

    while (!done)
    {
        printf("\nMENU OPTIONS:\n");
        printf("1. Add a product number\n");//Okay
        printf("2. Remove a product number\n");
        printf("3. List the products for a supplier\n");
        printf("4. List all unique supplier types\n");
        printf("5. Show profit margin for a specific supplier type\n");
        printf("6. Show total profit\n");//Okay
        printf("7. Quit\n");//Okay
        printf("Enter a selection (1-7): ");

        scanf("%d", &selection);
        char garbage = 'a';
        scanf("%c", &garbage);

        switch(selection){
        case 1:
            addProduct();
            break;
        case 2:
            removeProduct();
            break;
        case 3:
            listProduct();
            break;
        case 4:
            listSupplierTypes();
            break;
        case 5:
            supplierTypeProfit();
            break;
        case 6:
            totalProfit();
            break;
        case 7:
            done = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid selection.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Problem is likely in the code that you haven't shown to us.

Comment: Your code is fine - show us the actual problem, please!

Comment: Is "line 4" the first `scanf` call?

Comment: Yes, the after first scanf call is where the segfault comes in.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>[`remove`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) is the name of a standard function, declared in `<stdio.h>`. Defining your own object or other entity with the same name has undefined behavior. The call may be trying to store an `int` value at the address of the `remove()` function.</strike>

Try picking a different name.

**UPDATE:** I think I was mistaken. Function names defined in standard headers are reserved for use as identifiers *with external linkage*; they're also reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope if the relevant header is `#include`d. Neither should apply in your case. It's still a good idea to avoid defining such identifiers yourself, though.

Also, this probably isn't related to the symptom you're seeing, but

```
scanf("%d", &obj);
```

has undefined behavior if the input is a syntactically valid integer whose value is outside the range of `int`.

Execution *does* reach your "Does not get here" line. You're not seeing it because the buffered output isn't printed before the program dies.  Change this:

```
printf("Does not get here");
```

to this:

```
printf("Does not get here\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

When I run your program under `gdb`, I see the seg fault at:

```
if ((*walker).number == remove)
```

I also get several warnings during compilation:

```
c.c: In function ‘addProduct’:
c.c:32:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
c.c:38:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:134:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
c.c:134:9: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
c.c:134:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]
```

which could easily cause memory corruption.  Fix those and see what happens.

**UPDATE 2:**

I don't know what other programs your code may still have, but this:

```
while (!(walker = NULL))
{  
    if ((*walker).number == remove)
    {  
        (*prev).next = (*walker).next;
    }
}
```

is almost certainly wrong.  You're using an assignment `=` operator where you probably want an equality comparison `==`.  And after fixing that, the code would be clearer as follows:

```
while (walker != NULL)
{
    if (walker->number == remove)
    {
        prev->next = walker->next;
    }
}
```

That's just what jumped out at me when I took a very quick look after gdb told me the segfault was on the line `if ((*walker).number == remove)`.

Try using a debugger yourself, fix one problem at a time, and pay attention to any compiler warnings.

Comment: I tried this, but I don't think the error is here either. I changed all instances of remove to takeaway and the effect was the same, with a segfault as soon as I entered a value for the first scanf call.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: What value did you enter?

Comment: just single digit integers, like 3

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try fixing those errors and get back to you to let you know whether or not I was successful

Comment: Okay, I went back through and fixed up the warnings, but I still get the segfault. Any idea why it would segfault at this point?

Comment: @WhatsInAName: Without knowing exactly what the modified code looks like?

Comment: I found it... I set walker equal to NULL instead of checking if it was NULL. I'm a dumbass, but hopefully a better programmer for it.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: Hmm, did you really find it less than a minute after I updated my answer to say the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your printf does not appear because it didn't flush from the buffer, just use a "\n" at the end of the string and you will see it:

```
printf("Does not get here\n");
```

And so, the error, is not at `scanf`, but at this line:

```
walker = (*head).next;
```

As I could see, the program may reach there while `head` is not allocated, so you can check it at the beginning of the function:

```
void removeProduct(){
    int remove = 0;
    char kill_char = 'a';
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("No product to remove!\n");
        return;
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is any other errors, but this is the one I noticed.

BTW, you can avoid using `kill_char` by inserting a space at the beginning and end of format string on `scanf`:

```
scanf(" %d ", &remove);
```

It will skip all white characters (as tabs, spaces and line breakers). And, if you really just want to skip one, and only one, character, you can use `*` to ignore the match:

```
scanf("%d%*c", &remove);
```